# Mixing ordinary modules and external modules in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, phpstorm

Is there any problem mixing two types of modules in TypeScript? I mean something like follow:

```
/// <reference path="./FirstModule.ts" />

import SecondModule = require("./SecondModule");

class MainClass extends SecondModule
{
    private fm : FirstModule;

    constructor() {
        this.fm = new FirstModule();
    }
}
export = MainClass;
```

I'm having complicated problems with my TypeScript code and I'm not sure if this is the root. My problem is that while the compiler gives out no error, at run time the `FirstModule` is not recognized. I'm using **PhpStorm** and I can see that it tries to compile my code without any `--out` option. Here's the command:

```
/usr/local/bin/tsc --sourcemap MainClass.ts --module amd
```

Is the `--out` option needed here?

Comment: I'm not so sure, but I think you just need to require `FirstModule` similarly to how you've required `SecondModule`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, you don't want to mix and match internal and external modules.

The easiest solution is to use external modules throughout (so remove `module FirstModule` from the `FirstModule.ts` file and import it just like the second module).

```
import FirstModule = require("./FirstModule.ts");

import SecondModule = require("./SecondModule");

class MainClass extends SecondModule
{
    private fm : FirstModule;

    constructor() {
        this.fm = new FirstModule();
    }
}
export = MainClass;
```

Comment: I did that but is there any reason why? There's no text on this or at least I couldn't find any.

Comment: Internal modules are singleton instances, whereas external modules are loaded and executed on demand. It is not possible to generate JavaScript that would satisfy both of these styles, which is why it is hard to mix them.

Comment: External modules are singletons as well

Comment: Not in JavaScript terms - unless your module loader does something special there is every chance that you will have multiple instances when the same module is imported in different places in your application.

Comment: `there is every chance that you will have multiple instances when the same module is imported in different places in your application. ` Its the same javascript object returned everytime you do a `require` call. Both `amd` and `commonjs`. Otherwise the application would be much slower.

Comment: `Otherwise the application would be much slower.` every project has a `Utils` module used in every other file. You don't want that to get re-executed for *every* file ;)